# SQL Server Stored Proc: Return ID of row deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc where I am deleting a row from a table.

Is there a way to return the ID of the row deleted? I know there's a way to do it with inserting (SCOPE_IDENTITY()), but it doesn't seem to work for deletions.

The code:

```
BEGIN   
  declare @returnVal int
  DELETE FROM table WHERE num = 1;

  set @returnVal = /*HOW TO GET ID OF ROW DELETED?*/
END;
```

Comment: please show the code of the SP -- otherwise there will be no way to help you (besides guessing which could take a while.)

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() is used to get the last created/Inserted ID in a table. it doesnt give you the last deleted id.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can. From [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/):-

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID INT, TEXTVal VARCHAR(100))
----Creating temp table to store ovalues of OUTPUT clause
DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE (ID INT, TEXTVal VARCHAR(100))
----Insert values in real table
INSERT TestTable (ID, TEXTVal)
VALUES (1,'FirstVal')
INSERT TestTable (ID, TEXTVal)
VALUES (2,'SecondVal')
----Update the table and insert values in temp table using Output clause
DELETE
FROM TestTable
OUTPUT Deleted.ID, Deleted.TEXTVal INTO @TmpTable
WHERE ID IN (1,2)
----Check the values in the temp table and real table
----The values in both the tables will be same
SELECT * FROM @TmpTable
SELECT * FROM TestTable
----Clean up time
DROP TABLE TestTable
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. Surprised it's that convoluted.

Comment: NEver absolutely, never use the second code becasue triggers processs multiple records not one at a time. Any trigger that sets a value for a field in inserted or deleted to a scalar variable is wrong and needs to be fixed. The first is correct, So I won't downvote it.

Comment: @HLGEM:- Thats correct. Didnt want to mislead or give wrong solution. Deleted that.!!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to run 2 commands: SELECT to retrieve ID  and DELETE to actually perform deleteion.

```
BEGIN   
  declare @returnVal int
  SELECT @returnVal = ID FROM table WHERE num = 1;
  DELETE FROM table WHERE num = 1;
END;
```

Unless you delete based on ID - in that case you already know it.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert an `OUTPUT` clause between the `DELETE FROM` and `WHERE`:

```
DECLARE @returnVal TABLE ([id] [int] NOT NULL)

DELETE FROM table
  OUTPUT deleted.[id] INTO @returnVal 
  WHERE num = 1;

/* @returnVal contains the [id] values of all deleted rows. */
```

In a `DELETE` statement, you can access the data of deleted rows by the auto-created `deleted` table alias.